# исключение цифры в sql запросе

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте.

Есть у меня в базе строки, в некоторых есть цифра 2, как мне вывести все строки кроме той, в которой есть эта цифра. Пробовал NOT like '%2%', не получается... Или может можно просто в PHP скрипте исключить эту цифру при выводе? Помогите пожалуйста, весь измучался уже, часа 2 страдаю сижу, пытаюсь как то вывести без этой цифры

```
$avs = mysql_query("select * from fr where idus='1'");
while ($av = mysql_fetch_array($avs)) {
   $trs = mysql_query("select * from us where id='$av[id]'");
   while ($tr = mysql_fetch_array($trs) { 
echo $tr[id];
}
}
```

Вот из us надо вывести все id, кроме id 2

Comment: Текст запроса полность

Comment: Смотрите, редактировал

Comment: `id` какого типа? `char`, `Int`? если `int`, то приведите к `char`: `not cast(id as char) like '%2%'`

Comment: А можно полностью скрипт, я просто вставил сразу после '$av[id]' и не работает

Comment: Вот так что ли? `select * from us where id='$av[id]' not like '%2%'` Но это же очевидный бред. Скрипт полностью можно за отдельную плату

Comment: Не так, а так, как вы показали, через char

Comment: Послушайте, никто не может знать наверняка что Вы куда подставили и что в итоге получилось. Что в таких условиях можно сказать? Кроме того не определились какого типа Ваш id, это важно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разве так даёт с 2-ками?

```
select * from us where id='$av[id]' and id not like '%2%'
```

Comment: Спасибо, а не знаете как вывести одну строку по нескольким параметрам, то есть WHERE id='$av[id]' AND id='$av[idus]'

Comment: Вероятно, нужно заменить AND на OR.

Comment: Точно, не проверил, ступил что-то.

Answer (score 0):

Может сделать то что вы хотите одним запросом, вложенные циклы на php значительно медленнее единого запроса.

```
select *
  from fr
  join us on us.id=fr.id
 where fr.idus='1' and fr.id!=2
```

Исключает записи с id=2. Если исключить надо именно содержащие двойку, как вы написали в вопросе (т.е. и 12 и 25), то поправить условие на not like.

Если вам все таки кажется, что вложенный цикл необходим (хотя скорее всего вам кажется неправильно) вы можете в начале цикла перед выполнением запроса сделать нужную проверку и вообще не выполнять подзапрос для не нужных данных:

```
while ($av = mysql_fetch_array($avs)) {
   if($av[id]==2) continue;
   $trs = mysql_query("select * from us where id='$av[id]'");
   ...
}
```